# Would questions asking about the reality of a CGI scene be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, I want to know whether this scene does depict a correct number of 10.000 people or is it just an exaggeration.

Are such questions on-topic?

Comment: You want someone else to pause the video and count for you? That's what it seems like the question would be about

Comment: Maybe a source from an insider would work?

Answer (score 3):

### Frankly, no

This would fall under the heading of "[**trivia**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"

> Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.

Why is it "unimportant"?

Because does it really *matter* if they CGI'd 10000 people or just 9999?

Obviously not.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if it's 10000 or 9999. But it relatively matters if it's 10000 and 1000. The difference is just one [order of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude "Order of magnitude - Wikipedia"), and I think it does add to the understanding or appreciation of the movie.

Comment: I recently saw something about a movie (Troy?) where they had to limit the number of ships shown on screen because the more correct number made it look ridiculous. In the end it is irrelevant whether you see 1,000 or 5,000 or 10,000, what you see is "a lot" and nobody is going to count them.

Comment: May be it goes something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0Z0raWIHXk